# Overuse of var in C#

Tags: c#, coding-standards

With in the introduction of anonymous types in C# we got the `var` keyword.

Now people use `var` everywhere instead of the correct type. The reasons I've heard given for this are:

- It makes refactoring easier
- It's shorter
- it improves readability

A common example might be

```
var result = client.GetResult(query);
```

is better than:

```
MyObject result = client.GetResult(query);
```

Because if you refactor GetResult to return a different object; for example:

```
MyOtherObject result = client.GetResult(query);
```

you don't have to also refactor the calling code.

However I recently had to do the following refactoring

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> GetResult(query)
```

to

```
Task<List<MyObject>> GetResult(query)
```

The calling code was along the lines of

```
//return true if there are any results
var result = client.GetResult(query);
if(result != null)
{
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Which after the refactoring would still compile and always return true. Whereas the explicitly typed form would have thrown a compilation error.

So. The question is. Given that there are downsides to using var instead of the explicitly typed variable. Is it simply a case of coding style preference, or are there clear reasons to use, or not use var in this fashion? (ie. other than where required with anonymous types)

Comment: i think i would try to think about the project priorities. Are you making medical or military equipment? Dealing with highly private or sensitive information? If so, explicit typing can help with protection. If I'm making a survey site for coworkers only, then spending little time is more important.

Comment: hi @gnat, no i don't think that's a duplicate. You can see its been closed due to poor phrasing of the question. Where as mine is answerable. you would have to read the closed question and infer from the fact that its closed that the answer to mine is 'yes', when in fact there could be good technical reasons to use or not use var

Comment: Your example, IMO, is not one of the refactoring cases. You are changing the way that method behaves (from sync to async), which completely changes the signature of the method. You're right that not using `var` here would help a little bit in detecting the error when changing method signature. However, for such a change, I'll always review all references anyway.

Comment: I've edited to make it slightly clearer. Its an interesting case where the change of return type changes the way the method is called as well as the expected return type. but you can imagine other scenarios. In fact in an other change the return type changed from a simple list to a Lazily called list in a wrapper with a total. so instead of calling result.Count() you called result.Count

Comment: Is Visual Studio not powerful enough when you refactor a method signature to automatically update the `MyObject` to `MyOtherObject` ?

Comment: I'd go further than @HarryNinh and say that if you are changing the return type from `IEnumerable<MyObject>` to `Task<List<MyObject>>` then you are completely changing what the method does and so should have changed the method name too. Renaming from `GetResult` to `GetResultTask` would have instantly then picked up all the places where the calling code needed changing.

Comment: Regarding your question, the use of `var` is very much a style thing. Some (like myself) use it everywhere. Others hate it so much they even define a type called `var` to try and block it's use. It's a subjective thing. Finding objective reasons for either approach is hard.

Comment: @DavidArno the rename refactor would have been automatically applied to all references. But "its good because you don't have to refactor" is an argument I've heard in favour of var. The question is really about assessing those arguments rather than putting forward one or other as true

Comment: also... I guess there is an amount of subjectiveness about some of the arguments for or against. However, all coding standards are subjective, some are mature enough that they have achieved the status of convention and some are considered bad enough they are seen as universally 'bad'. What im interested in here is whether the 'bad' example I give, undermines the generally accepted 'goodness' of var, or whether there are real (technical or conventional) good reasons for var which override this one bad example. or indeed if the example is invalid in some way

Comment: But you wouldn't want to use the "rename refactor" in this case as you'd want to rewrite all the calling code. I feel your example is invalid as using such an auto-refactor would be a bad thing to do in this case. From experience, those that use `var` a lot, also tend to use a more declarative programming approach, avoid mutability, write shorter methods and classes, write unit tests (which would have failed after your `Task` change) etc. It's part of a mindset. Looking at `var` in isolation therefore misses the point to a certain extent.

Comment: Actualy it was the unit tests which were all passing erroniously

Comment: I love `var` so much that ie even when I use the `TryGetValue` from a dictionary I define the result variable as `var foo = (string)null;` rather then `string foo;`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FWIW I do find that `var` is overused. That doesn't mean it shouldn't be used though. These are the standards we use at my workplace.

1. Use `var` when the type is obvious.

   ```
   var foo = new Foo();
   ```
2. Don't use `var` when the return type isn't obvious.

   ```
   Foo foo = service.GetItem();
   ```
3. Don't use `var` when the method returns a concrete type.

   ```
   ICollection<Foo> items = new List<Foo>();
   ```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it's pure opinion. Sure, in your workplace, these rules apply. So what? In other workplaces, other rules apply. It therefore isn't a useful answer.

Comment: @DavidArno I didn't have a ton of time to justify these here, but I will later. It's maybe pure opinion as written, but there are objective arguments for all of this.

Comment: I very much doubt it, but I'm happy to be proven wrong. In the meantime, the upvotes show that some people at least agree with your opinions.

Comment: @DavidArno: I've been doing C# for awhile now, and these are precisely the guidelines I use.  I use them because they make sense.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Clearly they are a popular set of guidelines. 2 and 3 make no sense to me though. I guess it depends whether one is a "I've used C# for a while" person, or a "I've used C# and F# for a while". For me, F#'s "infer everything" approach makes sense, so I'd use `var` in all three cases. Though I'd probably never write example (3) as it's likely to be followed by a bunch of `Add()` calls, which don't fit the approach I take to coding and I wouldn't have a method return a concrete type, if it could return an interface implementation.

Comment: @DavidArno: Sometimes you actually have to declare the type to make the code work, as C#'s type inference isn't perfect.  I do this in a `foreach` from time to time, even though the convention is to use `var`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, sure, though that should be a very rare occurrence in well-written code. And C#'s inference rules can be worked around, eg the existence of libraries that allow `var` to be used with lambdas, along the lines of `var square = Lambda<double>(f => f * f);`, which is much nicer to read than `Func<double, double> square = f => f * f;`.

Comment: I always use `var` in each and every situation where it's possible to use it and I never ever had any problems working with it. The second example is invalid as the `GetItem` method is very generic and probably would return an object that needs to be casted. If the service however returns foos then I'd call it a fooService and wouldn't need an explicit type either. Other possibilities are `GetItem<Foo>` or just `GetFoo`.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated , use of `var` is totally optional (other than declaring anonymous type). It is only a coding style preference.

I would use explicit type declaration when assigning value from a function. But it is only for the readability, not for the advantage if and when the calling function would be refactored.

The quoted example is indeed bad. Usually we'd perform an operation on the returned object. If there were some operations performed on the returned object from `client.GetResult`, definitely there would be a compilation error.

We don't normally return `true` or `false` after checking null. The called function can very well return `true / false` itself.
Or, as the return value before refactoring was `IEnumerable<MyObject>`  the function `client.GetResult` could have returned an empty list (*Null object pattern?*) instead of `null`....just saying..